# How to secure connection between Vb6 application and mssql server?

Tags: sql-server, vb6, ado

I am working on a legacy application which uses sqloledb provider and activex data objects to connect to mssql database. Now I need to encrypt the connection between the application and server without force encryption option in sql server.

I have installed a self signed certificate in the sql server instance and tried putting the `Encrypt=true` and `Trustservercertificate=true` in connection string. But the connection is not encrypted.

I have tried using ODBC provider with ADO and while using `encrypt=true` and `trustservercertificate=true`, I am getting a SSL security error which opening the connection.

Please let me know how to establish a secure connection using ADO 2.8 library.

```vb
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim sConnectionString As String
    Dim strSQLStmt As String

     '-- Build the connection string
     'sConnectionString = "UID=userid;PWD=password;Initial Catalog=EHSC_SYM_Kings_Development;Server=EHILP-257\MIB14;Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Encrypt=YES;trustServerCertificate=YES"
     'sConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=192.168.27.91\MIB14;Initial Catalog=EHSC_SYM_Kings_Development;User Id=userid;Password=password;Encrypt=YES;trustServerCertificate=YES"
     'sConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};server=192.168.27.91\MIB14;user id=userid;password=password;Initial Catalog=EHSC_SYM_Kings_Development;Encrypt=Yes;trustServerCertificate=True"
     sConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=192.168.27.91\MIB14;Database=EHSC_SYM_Kings_Development;Uid=userid;Pwd=password;Encrypt=yes;trustServerCertificate=True"

     strSQLStmt = "select * from dbo.patient where pat_pid = '1001'"

    'DB WORK
    Dim db As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim result As String

    db.ConnectionString = sConnectionString
    db.Open 'open connection

    With cmd
      .ActiveConnection = db
      .CommandText = strSQLStmt
      .CommandType = adCmdText
    End With

    With rs
      .CursorType = adOpenStatic
      .CursorLocation = adUseClient
      .LockType = adLockOptimistic
      .Open cmd
    End With

    If rs.EOF = False Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        Let result = rs.Fields(0)
    End If
    'close conns
    rs.Close
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you not use the `SQLNCLI11` provider? Then https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax#enabling-encryption should apply.

Comment: I have tried using ado.net, but that is not an activex component, so i need to create an activex wrapper around ado.net to use it in my vb6 application. Still my application uses ado.recordset and ado.net uses dataset. so converting dataset into recordset is a performance overhead, so i cannot use ado.net.

Comment: SQLNCLI11 works fine with ADO 2.8, you just need to specify it in the connection string - https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-oledb-provider/

Comment: Its one of the things i tried. It doesn't work. I have added a sample of the things i have tried.

Comment: @SaiManibalan, ADO is an ActiveX component, SQLNCLI is the OLE DB provider ADO uses. Make sure you are using the [native client version that supports TSL 1.2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server). You might consider using the newer [msoledbsql provider instead](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56730).

Comment: @DanGuzman, I have installed the new msoledbsql and that too didn't work. The connection is established but its not encrypted. I have already updated the native client but of no use.

Comment: Verify your SQL Server version and patch level supports TLS 1.2 per the article I referenced.

Comment: I managed to make it work using {SQL Server Native Client 11.0} ODBC driver. Thanks so much

Comment: @SaiManibalan you should add an answer here (to your own question) with the details- that may help someone else in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions, I finally managed to make the connection secure by changing the driver to sqlserver native client 11(ODBC). Looks like sqloledb doesn't have support for tls. Changing the driver to ODBC doesn't seem to change the behaviour much. Rest of my code works fine without any changes

```
sConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=192.168.27.91\MIB14;Database=xxxxxxxx;user id=xxxxxxx;password=xxxxxxxxx;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes"
```

Comment: Note: remove or mask your password (assuming is a real one).

Answer (score 1):

Just went through this myself.

For your original connection string the keyword you're looking for is **not** "Encrypt=true" or "Encrypt=yes" like most of the internet would lead you to believe. It's "Use Encryption for Data=true".

So your connection string becomes:

```
sConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=192.168.27.91\MIB14;Database=EHSC_SYM_Kings_Development;Uid=userid;Pwd=password;Use Encryption for Data=true;trustServerCertificate=True"
```

The trustservercertificate=true is just for testing with self-signed certs... and exposing yourself to man-in-the-middle attacks ;)

For reference this was tested with:
VB6 connecting to SQL Server 2016 using SQLNCLI11 provider via ADODB.